# Android View background layout problem

Tags: android, listview, layout, background-color

I am trying to use a empty View to indicate the color for each item in a ListView.

The idea is that the rowColor View is just a 3dp wide line that should automatically size to the height of secondLine and thirdLine (note that all of the content is set in code including the background color of rowColor and that firstLine and thirdLine are often set to GONE).

It shows up perfectly in Eclipse's Graphical Layout but the rowColor does not show up at all on my phone (running 2.3.3) and all the views are stacked. Any idea how to fix it?

The following code for the list_row was adopted from [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/). I've provided all the code that I would think works based on that layout, but not even close. Does that layout still work?

list_row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="First Line" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/rowColor"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/thirdLine"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rowColor"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Third Line" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rowColor"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"
    android:layout_above="@id/thirdLine"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Second Line" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

ListViewTest.java Activity here: http://pastie.org/2035822

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try "wrap_content", see what that does

Comment: Does it ever show up? or is it only missing when firstList is GONE

Comment: Well rowColor never actually has content, just a background color. It doesn't show up for wrap_content or match_parent, or when firstLine is GONE. I only see it when I have it's height set to some size like 40dp.

Comment: Update: Disregard my last comment. The code above is much more simplified from what I was actually using to test before, but does not display correctly at all.. anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your layout in several emulators (from 2.1 to 2.3.3) and it works fine, with or without setting the first TextView visibility to View.GONE.

It must be either a problem in your code elsewhere or a glitch of your specific device.

As a workaround, you can use:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

for your rowColor View. Since you are already defining the position of the top and bottom limits with `android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, the actual value of `layout_height` is irrelevant.

Comment: How exactly did you test it? As I said, it looks perfect in the Graphical Layout, but not on my phone. What I posted was actually a simplified version of what I was using, but now I'm having problems even getting that to display right. I'll add more code to my question.

Comment: I would say to add **less**, **not more** code to it. Trim it until you find what's wrong. I pasted the layout in Eclipse and added it to a dummy project. I then run it through several emulators as I said above, not just the Graphical layout in the IDE.

Comment: I was hoping you had actually used it in a ListView. I provided the additional code that should make it work, but it doesn't. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently, and I found that a `View` with no content apart from a background color will not appear in a `RelativeLayout`.

If you can, try converting your layout to a `LinearLayout`.  This seems to work for me.